# Implement recent security patches immediately in Magento

Tags: patch, magento-1.8

While I am trying to update security patches I got following error message.

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 37.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 44.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 55.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 39 with fuzz 1 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 537 (offset 1 line).
patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 442.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php.rej
```

How can I update patches in this regard ??

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any custom changes in those core files?  The problem is either that or version missmatch with the patch file. A solution could be to manually apply the patch to the file by opening up the `PATCH.xxxxx-xxxxx.sh` file and look at the file paths and line numbers to compare and see where the added/changes lines should go (+ in front) and which lines should be deleted (- in front).

Comment: Thanks @Christoffer for your reply. 

**Do you have any custom changes in those core files?**

Which files did you mention here?? I did not change any thing. Thanks

Comment: For example app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php that is mentioned in your post

Comment: Thanks @Christoffer for your reply. I did not change any code of those files.